# Python, how to print Japanese, Korean, Chinese strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

In Python, for Japanese, Chinese, and Korean,Python can not print the correct strings, for example `hello` in Japanese, Korean and Chinese are:

```
こんにちは
안녕하세요
你好
```

And print these strings:

```
In [1]: f = open('test.txt')

In [2]: for _line in f.readlines():
   ...:     print(_line)
   ...:     
こんにちは

안녕하세요

你好


In [3]: f = open('test.txt')

In [4]: print(f.readlines())
[ '\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf\n', '\xec\x95\x88\xeb\x85\x95\xed\x95\x98\xec\x84\xb8\xec\x9a\x94\n', '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\n']

In [5]: a = '你好'

In [6]: a
Out[6]: '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
```

My Python version is 2.7.11 and OS is Ubuntu 14.04

How to handle these `'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\n'` strings.

Thanks!

Comment: Iterate over the file and print the individual elements. `for line in f.readlines(): print line`

Comment: I had no problem printing.

In [5]: print(f.readlines())
['こんにちは\n', '안녕하세요\n', '你好\n']

Comment: What do you mean by handling those strings?

Comment: @user161151, you can't grantee that you can print these string correctly all the time, if it prints `'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\n'` strings, it is hard to understand these outputs. So how to make sure it always print right strings.

Comment: what's the meaning of right strings?these {[u'\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f\n', u'\uc548\ub155\ud558\uc138\uc694\n', u'\u4f60\u597d']}?

Comment: @Hun: I am guessing you are using Python 3? Python 2 and 3 behave differently when it comes to handling unicode strings.

Comment: Yup, left python2 long time ago.

Comment: Can we get a confirmation which version of Python is being used here? I can reproduce the "problem" in Python 2.7, but not in Python 3.4.

Comment: @HannesOvrén, My python version is 2.7.11. OS is Ubuntu 14.04. System lauguage is English.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to read the text as unicode

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('test.txt','r','utf-8')
```

Second

When you print you should encode it like this

```
unicodeText.encode('utf-8')
```

Third

you should insure that your console support unicode display

Use

```
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

if it doesn't
try

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: When I tried `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` I got an error message: `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'`

Answer (score 2):

My python version 2.7.11 and operating system is Mac OSX,I write

```
こんにちは
안녕하세요
你好
```

to test.txt. My program is :

```
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-

import json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open("./test.txt", "r")
    a = f.readlines()
    print json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=False)
    f.close()
```

run the program, result:

```
["こんにちは\n", "안녕하세요\n", "你好"]
```

Comment: This is not the same case at all. You are writing the JSON string representation of the Python list, not the list itself.

Comment: I try some way, if you wanna get a list type data, the print data in list must be escaped.Do you know how to print a list data without escaped?

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the difference between

1. Printing a string
2. Printing a list

Or more generally, the difference between an objects "informal" and "official" string representation ([see documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)).

In the first case, the unicode string will be printed correctly, as you would expect, with the unicode characters.

In the second case, the items of the list will be printed using their *representation* and not their *string value*.

```
for line in f.readlines():
    print line
```

is the first (good) case, and

```
print f.readlines()
```

is the second case.

You can check the difference by this example:

```
 a = u'ð€œłĸªßð'
 print a
 print a.__repr__()
 l = [a, a]
 print l
```

This shows the difference between the special `__str__()` and `__repr__()` methods which you can play with yourself.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person name={}>'.format(self.name)

p = Person('Donald')
print p  #  Prints 'Donald' using __str__
p # On the command line, prints '<Person name=Donald>' using __repr__
```

I.e., the value you see when simply typing an object name on the console is defined by `__repr__` while what you see when you use `print` is defined by `__str__`.

Comment: OP uses Python3, your discussion is about Python2's behaviour.

Comment: @gboffi: Are we sure about that? You are the one who added the Python-3 tag, not OP. The print-as-a-function indicates Python 3, but since he could have used `from __future__ ...` we can't be 100% sure. I was uable to reproduce OP's problem, unless using Python 2.

Comment: @AlexanderYau please add `from __future__ import` to your question and/or add the relevant python2.x tag.

Comment: @gboffi, sorry about that.

Comment: Ooops, I was mistaken by the use of print as a function in the question, sorry about the noise...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import codecs

fp = codecs.open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8')

for line in fp:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also bothered by the same problem.
It is certainly the limitation of the font you are using.
It is set to "Consolas" by default.
You can change it to "**MS Gothic**" or "**NSimSun**".
I personally prefer the latter.
Both of them are capable of displaying Japanese/Chinese characters, but ensure that your system encoding is set to utf-8 as mentioned by sami in the above answer.
To change font in cmd, do:

1. Click on the cmd icon on top left of cmd window.
2. A drop-down menu appears. Select properties.
3. Select the font you prefer from the list shown in the second section.
4. Click OK.