# UnicodeEncodeError when printing Japanese characters from Django on Apache Server

Tags: django, apache, character-encoding, cjk

Inside any django view, I put a simple print() such that I can view the output on Apache's error log.

```
def list_of_main_units(request):
    print("some english characters")
    print("テスト３")
```

Here,
The first print works perfectly fine outputing the exact characters -> some english characters
But,
The problem is when I try outputting Japanese characters , it turns into some unicode literals.
Output for print("テスト３") -> \xe3\x83\x86\xe3\x82\xb9\xe3\x83\x88\xef\xbc\x93

Comment: you need to encode it in utf-8 before printing it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to print Japanese, Korean, Chinese strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639402/python-how-to-print-japanese-korean-chinese-strings)

Comment: If I encode it to utf-8 ..
Eg : print("テスト３".encode('utf-8'))
Result : b'\\xe3\\x83\\x86\\xe3\\x82\\xb9\\xe3\\x83\\x88\\xef\\xbc\\x93'

Comment: Thank you for your answer but regarding the link you provided.. most of the discussions are regarding Python2.. I use Apache with Django[Python3].. :(